# How to rename and manage tabs in kivy

Tags: python, tabs, kivy

Im just newbie in coding.
Im trying to write my 1st App for Android by YT lessons, i did this
code:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivymd.app import MDApp

from kivymd.uix.tab import MDTabsBase from kivymd.uix.floatlayout import MDFloatLayout from kivymd.icon_definitions import md_icons

KV = ''' <DrawerClickableItem@MDNavigationDrawerItem> focus_color: "#cce56f" text_color: "#4a4939" icon_color: "#ff6933" ripple_color: "#88e7e7" selected_color: "#3d5a80"


<DrawerLabelItem@MDNavigationDrawerItem> text_color: "#4a4939" icon_color: "#ff6933" focus_behavior: False selected_color: "#4a4939"
_no_ripple_effect: True


MDScreen: MDBoxLayout: orientation: "vertical"

MDTopAppBar:

MDTabs: id: tabs 

on_tab_switch: app.on_tab_switch(*args) MDNavigationLayout:

MDScreenManager:     MDScreen:

MDTopAppBar: title: "Навигация" elevation: 2 pos_hint: {"top": 1} md_bg_color: "#ff6933" specific_text_color: "#ffffff" left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state("open")]]



MDNavigationDrawer: type: "modal" id: nav_drawer radius: (0, 16, 166, 0)



MDNavigationDrawerMenu:

MDNavigationDrawerHeader: title: "Елена" title_color: "#4a4939" text: "ProstoFrizetava" spacing: "4dp" padding: "12dp", 0, 0, "56dp"

MDNavigationDrawerLabel: text: "Мой кабинет"

DrawerClickableItem: icon: "account-group" text: "Запись"

DrawerClickableItem: icon: "offer" text: "Мои услуги"

MDNavigationDrawerDivider:

MDNavigationDrawerLabel: text: "Labels"

DrawerLabelItem: icon: "information-outline" text: "Label"

DrawerLabelItem: icon: "information-outline" text: "Label" '''


class Tab(MDFloatLayout, MDTabsBase):
    '''Class implementing content for a tab.'''


class PersonApp(MDApp): def on_start(self): for name_tab in list(md_icons.keys())[15:30]: self.root.ids.tabs.add_widget(Tab(icon=name_tab, title=name_tab))

def on_tab_switch( self, instance_tabs, instance_tab, instance_tab_label, tab_text
    ):
        '''Called when switching tabs.

        :type instance_tabs: <kivymd.uix.tab.MDTabs object>;
        :param instance_tab: <__main__.Tab object>;
        :param instance_tab_label: <kivymd.uix.tab.MDTabsLabel object>;
        :param tab_text: text or name icon of tab;
        '''

print("tab clicked! " + tab_text)

def build(self): self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Light" self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Teal" return Builder.load_string(KV)


PersonApp().run()
```

I probably can't understand how to rename Tabs, in YT lessons guy using older version of kivy and its look different.

I would to manage and rename the tabs
Can please somebody explain it to me.
Thank you.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: It seems a couple of line breaks are missing in your code. Can you please fix this, so that a person trying to help you can just copy and paste this code.